# Send nginx X-Accel-Redirect request from remote server

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, django

I have 2 server first (domain.com) is a django/apache server, second (f1.domain.com) is a file server (nginx) where some files are protected and should be allow download only to registred user, so i have setup a nginx server with a

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name *.domanin.com;
        access_log /home/domanin/logs/access.log;
        location /files/ {
             internal;
             root /home/domanin;
        }
}
```

and from django I send a request via X-Accel-Redirect header, but dosen't work i think because come from a remote server, how can i accomplish my task?

regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the remote URL Host and URI pass it to proxy

```
location ^~ /redirect {
location ~ "^/redirect/(.*)/(.*)" {
resolver 8.8.8.8;
# internal;
include proxy_params;
proxy_pass http://$1/$2;
# echo proxy_pass;
# autoindex on;

# alias /var/www/;
}
}
```

The following links are excellent answer for your question.

[Nginx X-Accel-Redirect Remote URLS](http://kovyrin.net/2010/07/24/nginx-fu-x-accel-redirect-remote/)

[Nginx X-Accel-Redirect with resolver to resolve domain names](http://openhood.com/nginx/sysadmin/2011/06/28/nginx-useful-tips/)

Comment: Could you please cite the relevant content of the linked examples? StackExchange sites try hard to prevent linkrot, so in the interests of posterity, please expand your answers.